# npm run build getting hanged/struck in angular project while building image in docker

Tags: angular, docker, npm

I am learning docker and practicing it too, I am trying to create mono repo architecture for my project which is based on angular and I'm using docker to run it in container. When i execute the docker build command to build my application which is in monorepo my command line terminal was running for ever at the ***npm run build*** stage instead of showing image build success message. If i try the same commands in the standalone repo it successfully building images for the project.
I am not getting what was the issue can anyone help me out on this.

Here is my docker file instructions

```
    FROM node as builder
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    COPY . /app
    
    RUN npm i
    
    RUN npm run build application-one

    FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

    COPY --from=builder /app/dist/docker-angular-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-docker-practice",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: So how many applications does your monorepo have? you are building only application-one, what about the rest?

Comment: Yes at present i am having one application and trying to build that which is application-one

Comment: Sometimes npm does not behave as expected. In these cases, it is better to use yarn.

Comment: @MojtabaNejadPoorEsmaeili, nothing changed with yarn as well, still my build command executes forever in the terminal